# Why does not XmlSerializer recognize this attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have a simple class with two properties:

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class Response
{
    [XmlAttribute("code")]
    string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("message")]
    string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I try to deserialize an XML string with XmlSerializer:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string xml = "<response code=\"a\" message=\"b\" />";
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using(var sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
    {
        sw.Write(xml);
        sw.Flush();

        ms.Position = 0;

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));

        ser.UnknownAttribute += new XmlAttributeEventHandler(ser_UnknownAttribute);

        var obj = ser.Deserialize(ms);
    }
}

static void ser_UnknownAttribute(object sender, XmlAttributeEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The `UnknownAttribute` event gets fired at the `code` attribute, it does not get deserialized.
What is the reason for this? Am I using the XmlAttributeAttribute wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the attributes are not `public` in your class:

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class Response
{
    [XmlAttribute("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx) of `XmlAttributeAttribute` (emphasis is mine):

> You can assign the XmlAttributeAttribute **only to public fields or public properties** that return a value (or array of values) that can be mapped to one of the XML Schema definition language (XSD) simple types (including all built-in datatypes derived from the XSD anySimpleType type).

Comment: OBVIOUSLY!!! Thanks :). I have been staring at the code and googling for half an hour now. I'll accept the answer as soon as it is enabled.